# How do I teleport all nearby entities within a certain radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Could someone tell me how I can teleport all entities in a 5x5 block range to a certain location, for example to `-2697 80 -3401`.
I want to teleport a cat, a horse, and a villager to my original house.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in 1.13.2 or 1.14.*, you should be able to do this:

```
tp @e[dx=5,dy=5,dz=5] -2697 80 -3401
```

This will teleport all entities around you in a 5x5x5 cube to the point `-2697 80 -3401`.

If you want to teleport all entities in a cube around a specific point to your old house, this should work:

```
tp @e[x=100,y=150,z=200,dx=5,dy=5,dz=5] -2697 80 -3401
```

This will teleport all entities around the position `x=100,y=150,z=200` in a 5x5x5 cube to `-2697 80 -3401`.

Try it out, I think it could be what you want.

Comment: Worked for cat/horse. Any idea how to the the villager? thank you so much btw!

Comment: Does this work for Bedrock?