# How to make zombies spawn faster and in larger groups in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How to make zombies spawn faster and in larger groups using a command block on the Switch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Can you clarify: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello there, should it be a java edition question I would be able to answer you right away. So I would be providing you with some ideas instead of writing you an incompetent answer. Note that the following should happen in a datapack: in the tick function, check for new mobs without a certain tag and summon mobs at their location, finally tagging them with that specific tag. If you wish to have randomized zombie surges you could create a few randomization predicates in the datapack.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several simple things that may help:

- I don't know about increasing the total spawn rate of zombies but you
  could increase the concentration of hostile mobs by lighting up
  nearby areas as this forces the hostile mobs to only be able to spawn
  in the dark areas that you want them to spawn in.
- Alternatively, you could build the area in which you want zombies to
  spawn in the air to make sure that you only load in the platform so
  that hostile mobs can only spawn on the platform. If you you this
  method you will need to be at least 128 above the highest point on
  the ground to increase efficiency.
- You could also increase the tick speed thus increasing the amount of mobs spawning

Here is a slightly more complex way that works on Java but I am not sure about Bedrock:

- Spawn in zombie with a command block.
- Use spread player command to spread all the zombies in a certain area into another area.

Here is a link for more details:

[How do I teleport all nearby entities within a certain radius?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/354068/277689)

If possible, as commented by several people, could you be more specific and give us more information about why you need this for, whether you have access to command (which I assume you do as it is a tag) and several other factors that could help us help you.